# UWP: Navigation View does not fully extend into title bar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, desktop-application

In my UWP app, I'm trying to extend the navigation view into title bar. But the problem is it does not reach the title bar like below.

[image: title bar not taking full height]

What I want is like below.

[image]

You can see the "XAML Controls Gallery" and the back button are on the topmost position, in my case they are down. And I want to place my "Student Management" beside the back button like in the second image.

Below is my code.

App.xaml.cs

```
OnLaunched () {
    // entends views to the title bar
    var coreTitleBar = 
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HelloWorld"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{StaticResource NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground}"
    >

    <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                  BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                  TintColor="AliceBlue"
                  TintOpacity="0.6"
                  FallbackColor="White"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <NavigationView 
            x:Name="navView" 
            IsBackEnabled="True" 
            Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded" 
            SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
            PaneOpening="navView_PaneOpening"
            IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
            SelectionFollowsFocus="Disabled"
            Header="Students"
            PaneDisplayMode="Auto"
            Background="{StaticResource SystemChromeWhiteColor}" 
            OpenPaneLength="280" UseLayoutRounding="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="12" PaneTitle="Student Management"
            >
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="People" Content="Students" Tag="students"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Bookmarks" Content="Gradings" Tag="gradings"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="ContactInfo" Content="Statistics and Reports" Tag="reports"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Print" Content="Print" Tag="print"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Admin" Content="Users" Tag="users"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <ScrollViewer>
                <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace HelloWorld
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NavigationView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("loaded banana ---");
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Students));
        }

        private void NavigationView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("changed banana ---");
            if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
            {
                // if you have setting page, load here. 
            }
            else
            {

                NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

                switch (item.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    case "students":
                        sender.Header = "Students";
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Students));
                        break;
                    case "gradings":
                        sender.Header = "Gradings";
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Gradings));
                        break;
                    case "reports":
                        sender.Header = "Reports";
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Reports));
                        break;
                    case "print":
                        sender.Header = "Print";
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Print));
                        break;
                    case "users":
                        sender.Header = "Users";
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Users));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void navView_PaneOpening(NavigationView sender, object args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("opening");
            navView.Translation = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: Using WinUI**

I've tried WinUI to use `IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled` described in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#top-whitespace).
But doesn't work.

App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="HelloWorld.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HelloWorld">
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HelloWorld"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" // <- this is added according to documentation
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{StaticResource NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground}"
    >

    <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                  BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                  TintColor="AliceBlue"
                  TintOpacity="0.6"
                  FallbackColor="White"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <muxc:NavigationView 
            IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"
            x:Name="navView" 
            Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded" 
            SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
            PaneOpening="navView_PaneOpening"
            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
            SelectionFollowsFocus="Disabled"
            Header="Students"
            PaneDisplayMode="Auto"
            Background="{StaticResource SystemChromeWhiteColor}" 
            OpenPaneLength="320" 
            UseLayoutRounding="True" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            FontSize="14"
            PaneTitle="STUDENT MANAGEMENT" 
            CharacterSpacing="20" 
            FontStretch="SemiExpanded" 
            RequestedTheme="Default"
            >
            <muxc:NavigationView.PaneHeader>
                <Image Source="/Assets/logo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,5,5"></Image>
            </muxc:NavigationView.PaneHeader>
            <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="People" Content="Students" Tag="students" Width="320"/>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Bookmarks" Content="Gradings" Tag="gradings" Width="320"/>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="ContactInfo" Content="Statistics and Reports" Tag="reports" Width="320"/>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Print" Content="Print" Tag="print" Width="320"/>
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Admin" Content="Users" Tag="users" Width="320"/>
            </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <ScrollViewer>
                <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </muxc:NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Above usage, I got the following error.

```
Error   CS0426  
The type name 'NavigationView' does not exist in the type 'Controls'.
```

When I remove `muxc` around the navigation and its children, I got a warning in the `IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled` which says `The property 'IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled' was not found in type 'NavigationView'.` & `Unknown member 'IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled' on element 'NavigationView'` and can't run the project.

I'm using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` 2.5.0. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to set the `Margin` property of the `Grid` to let the navigation view extend into title bar. And you could add a `TextBlock` control over the `NaviagtionView` control to meet your second requirement.

Please check the following code as a reference:

```
<Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,-1,0,0">  <!--Use the Margin with a negative vlue.-->
    <Grid.Resources>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
              TintColor="AliceBlue"
              TintOpacity="0.6"
              FallbackColor="White"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <NavigationView 
        x:Name="navView" 
        IsBackEnabled="True" 
        Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded" 
        SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
        PaneOpening="navView_PaneOpening"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
        SelectionFollowsFocus="Disabled"
        PaneDisplayMode="Auto"
        Background="{StaticResource SystemChromeWhiteColor}" 
        OpenPaneLength="280" UseLayoutRounding="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="12"
        >
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="People" Content="Students" Tag="students"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Bookmarks" Content="Gradings" Tag="gradings"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="ContactInfo" Content="Statistics and Reports" Tag="reports"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Print" Content="Print" Tag="print"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Admin" Content="Users" Tag="users"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </NavigationView>
    <!--Add a TextBlock over the NaviagationView control to show a text beside the back button.-->
    <!--Note to put the TextBlock below the NavigationView to prevent the TextBlock from being hidden by the NavigationView.-->
    <TextBlock Text="Student Management" Margin="40,6,0,0"  FontSize="20"/>

</Grid>
```

In addition, there is an easier way to hide the title bar by using the `NavigationView` control in [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started) library. You could set the value of `IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled` property to `False` in `NavigationView` control referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#top-whitespace).

For example:

```
<muxc:NavigationView IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"
    x:Name="navView" 
    ……
   >
    ……
 </muxc:NavigationView>
```

Comment: I'm using WinUI as your suggestion because the Margin thing does not look good. I've updated my question. Could you please see it?

Comment: It seems no problem with you newly added code. You may need to check if the type of argument sender in NavigationView_SelectionChanged event handler and the navView_PaneOpening is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView. If the type of argument sender is correct(is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView), it is better if you could provide me a minimal sample by OneDrive or GitHub for testing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Here it is - https://github.com/Fluent-Design-Tester/Navigation-Demo.

Comment: I found there is folder called Microsoft in the Solution Explorer, which overwrites the Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace，causing the error. You need to delete the whole Microsoft folder. Note to Replace the original APIs related to NavigationView with APIs under Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it as you say and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please recommend the course or tutorial to learn UWP other than official documentation.

Comment: You could learn the **Windows 10 development for absolute beginners** video on Channel 9, or search the course **Getting started with UWP** on Channel 9.

Answer (score 2):

Add only property like `IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled` to false in `muxc:NavigationView` if didn't working so another property doesn't allow to control this property.

XAML code looks like -

```
<muxc:NavigationView
    ...
    IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"
    ... />
```